# Python: Maximum difference between elements in a list

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I need to find the maximum difference between elements in an unsorted list if the element to the right of the present element is greater. For eg:

```
myList = [2, 3, 8, 0, 7].
```

Function should calculate as follows:

```
present element = 2.
is 3 > 2? Yes. Then 3-2 = 1
is 8 > 2? Yes. Then 8-2 = 6
is 0 > 2? No. Go to the next element.
is 7 > 2? Yes. Then 7-2 = 5 and so on

Finally my output = 7
```

My first solution is as follows:

```
def maxDiff(a):
l = len(a)
arr = []
for i in range(l-1):
    for j in range(i+1, l):
        if a[j] > a[i]:
            diff = a[j] - a[i]
            arr.append(diff)
return (max(arr))
```

I was said that this is not an optimal solution. I came up with another solution which is as follows:

```
def maxDiff(a):
l = len(a)
diffList = []
for i in range(l-1):
    newList = a[i+1:]
    max1 = max(newList)
    difference = max1 - a[i]
    diffList.append(difference)
return (max(diffList))
```

My question is is the second solution correct? If yes, then is it optimal? What is the time complexity of both these functions? Is there any other solution that is more optimal?

Comment: What do you want to optimize? Runtime, memory consumption, some other variable? And your function is  correct if it produces the expected result. Did you check it?

Comment: the first one is worst case O(n^3)  as arr could theoretically be of length n.

Comment: in your second function you don't need to do the diffList array and then max (diffList), just store the current maximum.  i.e. for each iteration do if max < difference then max = difference;

Comment: And there is probably some way of not constantly recalculating the max each time i.e. caching.

Comment: Runtime. Both are correct. @DocDriven

Comment: I did without the diffList array. I got the correct result. I am looking for a way not calculating the max each time. @TimRutter

Comment: @Dave OP had an additional requirement: "...if the element to the right of the present element is greater. E:g., maxDiff([9,1,2]) should be 1, not 8.

Comment: what's wrong with `print(max(a)-min(a))`

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second solution still recalculates the max value of the prefix list on every iteration, which you don't need to do.

I think both of your solutions are correct, but the second one is still at least quadratic O(n^2) since you are performing linear-time operations (such as `max()`) in your for loop. So to answer your question: No, it's likely not an optimal solution.

If I understood the problem correctly, it can be solved using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Consider the following code:

```
def maxDiff(a):
    vmin = a[0]
    dmax = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if (a[i] < vmin):
            vmin = a[i]
        elif (a[i] - vmin > dmax):
            dmax = a[i] - vmin
    return dmax
```

Here we are simply keeping track of the smallest value encountered so far, and the largest difference, thus allowing us to iterate only once through the list without the need for storing any additional lists or doing any nested looping. The runtime of this should therefore be linear, O(n), in terms of comparison operations.

Comment: A caveat: It was not specified what the algorithm should do when the array is strictly descending. In such situations, OP's first algorithm will crash, the second one will yield a negative (incorrect) result and this one will simply return 0. You might want to handle this situation separately with a check.

Answer (score 3):

## using the new walrus operator (Python >3.8 req)

```py
    import sys
    lst = [7,1,5,4]
    
    minscan = sys.maxsize
    solution = max([x - (minscan := min(minscan,x)) for x in lst])
    print(solution if solution !=0 else -1)
```

Comment: explained also in https://youtu.be/UogkQ67d0nY

Answer (score 0):

```
def maxPairDiff(arr):
    listDiff=[]
    for p,i in enumerate(arr):
        evalList=[e for e in arr[p+1:] if e>i]
        if len(evalList)>0:
            listDiff.append(max(evalList)-i)
    return (max(listDiff))


givenList = [7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2]
print ("Required result is {}".format(maxPairDiff(givenList)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are though many ways to solve a single problem. i would suggest this way as will be a bit faster and is more pythonic.

```
mylist = [2, 3, 8, 0, 7]
max_diff = max( [mylist[i+1]-mylist[i] for i in range(len(mylist)-1) if mylist[i]<mylist[i+1]] )

print(max_diff)
```