# Finding the maximum increase within a given sequence

Tags: python

I am currently working on a function that takes a sequence and returns the maximum increase from one element to the other at a higher index. However, the function is not returning the correct maximum increase.

I have put a for loop inside a for loop, then tried to return the maximum value out of all the differences, which did not work (it said `'int' object is not iterable`)

```
def max_increase(seq):
    i = 0
    maximum_increase = 0
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        difference = 0
        for j in range(i + 1, len(seq)):
            difference = seq[j] - seq[i]
        if 0 <= maximum_increase < difference:
           maximum_increase = difference
    return maximum_increase
```

For `max_increase([1,2,3,5,0])`, it should return `4` since from the differences list `[1,2,4,-1,1,3,-2,2,-3,-5]`, the maximum is `4`. However, my function returns a negative value, `-1`.

Comment: No repro - I get 0 as output.

Comment: Anyway, the problem's just a typo - you need to indent your `if` by 1 more level so it's inside your 2nd `for`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Maximum difference between elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041365/python-maximum-difference-between-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: what should be as the output of `[3,2,1]`?

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation problem. This fixes it:

```
def max_increase(seq):
    i = 0
    maximum_increase = 0
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        difference = 0
        for j in range(i + 1, len(seq)):
            difference = seq[j] - seq[i]
            if 0 <= maximum_increase < difference:
                maximum_increase = difference
    return maximum_increase
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you have received help in debugging your code already, here is a short pythonic solution to the problem:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,5,0]
>>> inc = (i-el for p, el in enumerate(l) for i in l[p:])
>>> max(inc)
4
```

but even better is one that avoids creating unnecessary slices (at the cost of reversing the sequence):

```
import itertools as it


def incs(seq):
    pr = []
    for el in reversed(seq):
        print(f"{el} is compared with {pr}")
        yield (i-el for i in pr)
        pr.append(el)

seq = [1, 2, 3, 5, 0]
print("The max inc is", max(it.chain.from_iterable(incs(seq))))
```

which produces

```
0 is compared with []
5 is compared with [0]
3 is compared with [0, 5]
2 is compared with [0, 5, 3]
1 is compared with [0, 5, 3, 2]
The max inc is 4
```

Note: in case the increase is to be intended as the distance between the two numbers, i.e. always positive irrespective of sign, then make the change

```
yield (abs(i-el) for i in pr)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
my_l = [1,2,3,5,0]

max((e for i in range(len(my_l)) for e in (j - my_l[i] for j in my_l[i + 1:])))
```

output:

```
4
```